# How do you determine whether an user has deviated from a route?

Tags: ios, algorithm, dictionary

I am trying to determine whether or not an user has deviated from a given route. For example, in many GPS routing application modes, the application will recalculate a route if you have deviated too far from the current route.

More specifically, I am trying to find whether or not a given coordinate deviates past a threshold given a set of polylines.

What is the best way to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the closest line of that polylines set to the current point, then get distance, that's all. There's only one way, and no "best" way.

Comment: I probably should have clarified, by "best" I mean most efficient. Can you provide the calculation? Given that a polyline is made up of two GPS coordinates, how do you determine the distance given an arbitrary GPS coordinate? How do you extrapolate this across all polylines from the route, or is this a brute force operation?

Comment: Hmm. This requires constant tracking of current coordinate, with this you have to worry about at most three lines out of that polyline, the currently closest, and two adjacent ones. The answer applies to the case where the coordinate is random, say the user has been teleported. If the coordinate changes by small amounts between the iterations, the best way will be tracking 3-4 polylines and comparing the current position to them only.